# How to cast simple feature points along a line into segments with endpoints

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, r-sf

I have a number of geographic points along a line. Several of these points form segments defined by a column. I treat these as a simple feature and try to transform each segment into a line. However, when I use group_by I miss the endpoint of each segment, which corresponds to the first point of the next segment. What I would like, is that each line segment ends, where the next starts. In essences, this probably boils down to adding one extra row to the group_by command, or a similar approach. 
Thanks for your help.

```
SF_df <-   tibble(Segment = c("A","A","A", "B","B","B", "C","C","C"),Value = c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3), LAT = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), LONG = 1) %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("LONG", "LAT"), crs = "+proj=utm +zone=33    +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")
plot(SF_df)

SF_segs <- SF_df %>% group_by(Segment) %>% summarize(Value = mean(Value)) %>% st_cast("LINESTRING")
plot(SF_segs)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract the last row of each `Segment` adjust their labels, `rbind` to original object and `plot`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

temp_df <- SF_df %>%
            group_by(Segment) %>%
            slice(n()) %>%
            ungroup() %>%
            mutate(Segment = lead(Segment)) %>%
            slice(-n()) %>%
            rbind(SF_df)


SF_segs <- temp_df %>% 
             group_by(Segment) %>% 
             summarize(Value = mean(Value)) %>% 
             st_cast("LINESTRING")
plot(SF_segs)
```

[image]

Comment: That worked indeed! More complicated than I thought it would be,  but excellent solution.